# How to change SQL default convention?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing some SQL sentences and finally I get a code where some of the letters are big, some are small and it doesn't looks good, e.g:

```
SELECT * from dbo.Employee Where ...
```

I want to change the default convention that *sometimes* changes my code to big letters, does it possible?

Finally I see myself spending more time on changing the key letters to be camel letters which takes me some more time and it is a little bit annoying.

Comment: You haven't said what you're using to edit your SQL

Comment: copy paste, edditing by myself every code that is not as my preferable convention.

Comment: You didn't understand, I am editing because the compiler of the SQL sometimes changes my code to big letters, so I need to edit it letter... Oh if you asked where I write this code, maybe I didn't understand, so I write it on SQL Server 2008. And key letters are like select, from, where, group by, etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use any online SQL Formatter like [Instant SQL Formatter](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm) and specify what should be in upper case, lower case or camel case.